# How to get Nationality of a Country asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want nationality of a Country. If I type England then it will return the nationality of England. I don't know if cultureinfo help me or not.

```
string country = "England";
```

output should be: British

Can anybody help?

Comment: Your best bet is custom dictionary mapping name of country the way you like it to spell to "nationality" the way you define it.

Comment: This [link](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/world-countries-nationality.htm) and this [one](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/nationalities/) may help you to know list of countries and nationalities, then create a `Dictionary<string,string>` and set country as key and nationality as value, then you can find nationality based on country.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks man :))

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan You are welcome:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        //Init your dictonary as like this
        Dictionary<string, string> countryNationality = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "India", "Indian" }, { "England", "British" } };
        // Now access the value like this 
        string nationality = countryNationality["England"];//will give you British
        string anotherNationality = countryNationality["India"];//will give you British
```